# jenkins build tells my project is not a part of grails application

Tags: grails, build, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

HI im running a jenkins instance for a grails app build and deploy but, i am running into a problem now, somewhere during the buid it tell me that my checkedout project is not a part of grails application.
The message logged is :

```
Started by GitHub push by pedrospaulus
Building remotely on s-ea17527f in workspace /scratch/jenkins/workspace/cloudbees_doofry_jenkins_2
Checkout:cloudbees_doofry_jenkins_2 / /scratch/jenkins/workspace/cloudbees_doofry_jenkins_2 - hudson.remoting.Channel@3a1ecfab:s-ea17527f
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 7d9e4790f577b6c4d3a53338653647d1f1400701 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Commencing build of Revision 4716cf96f4edcc7eef3a4d6826ef3a966aa9a670 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision 4716cf96f4edcc7eef3a4d6826ef3a966aa9a670 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[cloudbees_doofry_jenkins_2] $ /opt/grails/grails-1.3.7/bin/grails war target/cloudbees_doofry.war --non-interactive
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /opt/grails/grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/cloudbees_doofry_jenkins_2
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 4346ms.
/scratch/jenkins/workspace/cloudbees_doofry_jenkins_2 does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
The following commands are supported outside of a project:
    add-proxy
    clear-proxy
    create-app
    create-plugin
    help
    list-plugins
    package-plugin
    plugin-info
    remove-proxy
    set-proxy
Run 'grails help' for a complete list of available scripts.
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
[cloudbees-deployer] Skipping deployment as build result is FAILURE
Sending e-mails to: pedrospaulus@gmail.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea what im doing wrong ??
tkx

Comment: Is `application.properties` in root of your git repository ? (not ignored)

Comment: @isammoc, yes application properties is included in the application that i have on github codebase? you think something can be wrong about that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in the context of the desired grails app to run the build.

Seems like `/scratch/jenkins/workspace/cloudbees_doofry_jenkins_2/your-grails-app` should be the base directory structure where you should kick of the build.

Comment: thankx indeed the project structure was bad i restructure it and every thing is OK now the build passed succefully.

Comment: @user1194455 If the answer was helpful, accepting it will help others following your path.